# per-instance application settings in Openbox

Tags: openbox, lxde

I need to run two instances of the same program, and have different Openbox properties for each.

Lets say, I want to run two instances of Thunderbird. Even when I create two symlinks, i.e.

```
/usr/bin/icedove-1
/usr/bin/icedove-2
```

both instances still have the same NAME and TITLE:

```
$ obxprop | egrep '_OB_APP'
_OB_APP_TYPE(UTF8_STRING) = "normal"
_OB_APP_TITLE(UTF8_STRING) = "Icedove Mail/News"
_OB_APP_CLASS(UTF8_STRING) = "Icedove"
_OB_APP_NAME(UTF8_STRING) = "Mail"
_OB_APP_ROLE(UTF8_STRING) = "3pane"
```

How can I distinquish between two instances of the same program?

Can I start a program with a parameter, which will change the `TITLE` or `NAME` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thunderbird, as a GTK+ application, supports a [`--class` command-line option](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-running.html) that sets the `WM_CLASS` property:

```
$thunderbird --class TEST &
$obxprop | grep 'OB_APP'
_OB_APP_TYPE(UTF8_STRING) = "normal"
_OB_APP_TITLE(UTF8_STRING) = "Mozilla Thunderbird"
_OB_APP_GROUP_CLASS(UTF8_STRING) = "TEST"
_OB_APP_GROUP_NAME(UTF8_STRING) = "thunderbird"
_OB_APP_CLASS(UTF8_STRING) = "TEST"
_OB_APP_NAME(UTF8_STRING) = "Mail"
_OB_APP_ROLE(UTF8_STRING) = "3pane"
```

Openbox supports per-application settings [determined by the window class](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Applications) using the `class` attribute on an `<application>` entry in `rc.xml`. You can launch your two copies of Thunderbird with different command-line options and apply your window manager settings by the class you give.

Other GTK+ applications will generally support the same behaviour.

Comment: that works perfectly. Now I have noticed, Thunderbird is being executed as `Exec=icedove %u`. Do you have any idea what the `%u` means?

Comment: `%u` [is replaced with "a single URL"](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s06.html) in the command line if you drag something onto the launcher icon.

Comment: @Michael Homer - so where should I put the class, infront or after `%u`?,i.e. `icedove --class TEST %u`, or `icedove %u --class TEST`?

Comment: `thunderbird --help` suggests options go before the URL parameter.